# JDialog gets hidden after casting JFileChooser

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

My program contains of a JDialog with a button which opens a JFileChooser. After Clicking on this Button my main JDialog gets hidden even if it's set to modal. This shouldnt happen.

What to do?

Comment: I suggest you to improve your question by reading the [Minimal, Complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `JDialog` as a *parent* to the `JFileChooser` should "hold" it in place.